# Read CSV file without scientific notation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes with one column, values as

df1:

```
0000D3447E
0000D3447E39S
5052722161014
5052722161021
5052722161038
00000E2377
00000E2378
0000F2892E
0000F2892EDI1
8718934652999
8718934653095
8718934653002
8718934653118
8718934653019
8718934653125
8718934653132
00000E2387
```

df2:

```
0000D3447E
0000D3447E39S
5052722161014
5052722161021
5052722161038
00000E2377
00000E2378
0000F2892E
00000E2387
```

when I merge these two dataframes I don't get the merged values which starts with "00000E"

I used:

```
df1[['PartNumber']] = df2[['PartNumber']].astype(str)
```

To convert the column dtype to string. But, still I'm not able get the merged values.

my question is how can I get these values which start with `00000E` when I merge the two dataframes.

Comment: please read and apply [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is the data source?

Comment: Data source is a CSV file

Comment: Copied your frames into text files and have no issues of values not showing when merging.

Comment: Btw, don't know if the code in your question will work though. Looks like you're mixing the df-labels?